# apache2 and sshd are listening, but only sshd is accessible from remote

Tags: apache2, aws, chef

I've just installed apache2 on Ubuntu (aws) using chef.

> Apache2 on Ubuntu Server: 10.1.1.1
>
> Client: 10.1.1.200

I've also verified that both tcp 22 (sshd) & tcp 80 (apache2) are listening

```
root@Ubuntu:/var/www# netstat -anp | egrep '22|80'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1469/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      16950/apache2   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1469/sshd       
root@Ubuntu:/var/www#
```

Processes also look good

```
root@Ubuntu:/var/www# ps -ef | egrep 'apache2|sshd'
root      1469     1  0 Sep29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root     16950     1  0 Sep29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16953 16950  0 Sep29 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16954 16950  0 Sep29 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root@Ubuntu:/var/www#
```

Service also running as usual

```
root@Ubuntu:/var/www# service apache2 status
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-09-29 23:36:49 UTC; 2h 13min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 55
   Memory: 6.5M
      CPU: 4.637s
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─16950 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─16953 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─16954 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Sep 29 23:36:47 Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Sep 29 23:36:47 Ubuntu apache2[16933]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Sep 29 23:36:48 Ubuntu apache2[16933]: AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for Ubuntu
Sep 29 23:36:48 Ubuntu apache2[16933]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the '
Sep 29 23:36:49 Ubuntu apache2[16933]:  *
Sep 29 23:36:49 Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
root@Ubuntu:/var/www#
```

However, when I try to access the server remotely via `http://10.1.1.1`, nothing happen. I don't have this problem with ssh on the same server.

I've also run tcpdump when trying to access the web server from remote but I did not see anything

**Test from client**

```
[root@Client]# curl 10.1.1.1:80
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.1.1.1:80; Connection timed out
[root@Client]#
```

But nothing seen on the server

```
root@Ubuntu:/var/www# tcpdump -nni eth0 port 80
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
root@Ubuntu:/var/www#
```

However, when I try the same thing with ssh, I'm able to access it remotely and traffic seen on tcpdump as expected.

```
[root@Client]# curl 10.1.1.1:22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
[root@Client]#
```

tcpdump on ssh

```
root@Ubuntu:/var/www# tcpdump -nni eth0 port 22 and host 10.1.1.200
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
02:03:04.320761 IP 10.1.1.200.35890 > 10.1.1.1.22: Flags [S], seq 1658944714, win 26883, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 52461068 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:03:04.320923 IP 10.1.1.1.22 > 10.1.1.200.35890: Flags [S.], seq 2270168630, ack 1658944715, win 26847, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 13211819 ecr 52461068,nop,wscale 7], length 0
02:03:04.321264 IP 10.1.1.200.35890 > 10.1.1.1.22: Flags [.], ack 1, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 52461069 ecr 13211819], length 0
02:03:04.321287 IP 10.1.1.200.35890 > 10.1.1.1.22: Flags [P.], seq 1:80, ack 1, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 52461069 ecr 13211819], length 79
02:03:04.321293 IP 10.1.1.1.22 > 10.1.1.200.35890: Flags [.], ack 80, win 210, options [nop,nop,TS val 13211819 ecr 52461069], length 0
02:03:04.326160 IP 10.1.1.1.22 > 10.1.1.200.35890: Flags [P.], seq 1:42, ack 80, win 210, options [nop,nop,TS val 13211821 ecr 52461069], length 41
02:03:04.326683 IP 10.1.1.1.22 > 10.1.1.200.35890: Flags [R.], seq 42, ack 80, win 210, options [nop,nop,TS val 13211821 ecr 52461069], length 0
02:03:04.326899 IP 10.1.1.200.35890 > 10.1.1.1.22: Flags [.], ack 42, win 211, options [nop,nop,TS val 52461075 ecr 13211821], length 0
02:03:04.326911 IP 10.1.1.1.22 > 10.1.1.200.35890: Flags [R], seq 2270168672, win 0, length 0
^C
9 packets captured
9 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
root@Ubuntu:/var/www#
```

**Update:** iptables output

Also, this box is installed on aws

```
root@Ubuntu:~# iptables -vL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
root@Ubuntu:~#
```

Comment: Do you have an ipv4 interface and an ipv6 interface? I’m not super familiar with netstat, but it looks like sshd is listening on both while the httpd is listening on just the ipv6 interface

Comment: Are you running a firewall? Add the output of `iptables -L` to your question.

Comment: Thanks Thomas & DTSCode. My question has been updated with iptables output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for your feedback. Apparently, aws only open ssh (tcp22) for this connectivity.

Once http (tcp80) is permitted on aws, I can access this box remotely.

I knew something was blocking as nmap shows filtered on tcp80 and open on tcp22, but had no clue it was aws at that moment.

**Before**

```
Nmap scan report for 10.1.1.1
Host is up (0.062s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 7.2p2 Ubuntu 4ubuntu2.2 (Ubuntu Linux; protocol 2.0)
80/tcp filtered  http    nginx 1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

**After**

```
Nmap scan report for 10.1.1.1
Host is up (0.062s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 7.2p2 Ubuntu 4ubuntu2.2 (Ubuntu Linux; protocol 2.0)
80/tcp open  http    nginx 1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

Answer (score 6):

Apache is listening on IPv6, not IPv4:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      16950/apache2
```

`tcp6` and `:::80` are both clues that Apache is listening on IPv6, not v4 (these would be `tcp` and `0.0.0.0:80` otherwise).

There are many solutions to this problem.  Probably the best one is to tell Apache to explicitly listen on IPv4.  Change your `Listen` directive from something like this:

```
Listen 80
```

to:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```